# Display and Hide graphs on button click in visual c++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, event-handling

I have a winform application in visual c++. There are two buttons in the window. "Button A" and "Button B". On clicking A a graph appears. On clicking B another graph appears but the graph of A disappears/hides and vice versa. How can i achieve this in visual c++?

Any suggestions

Regards

Edit: The graph is being generated by picking values from the database. I am able to do this. What i need is that when button A is clicked Graph A is displayed. When button B is clicked Graph B is displayed and Graph A is not and vice versa. By default no graph should be displayed and one should be able to toggle between the graphs by clicking on the respective button. I hope i am clear now

Comment: Showing/Displaying/Creating the graph or handling the button clicks ?

Comment: @Max i have edited the question...hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each picture in its own PictureBox control (e.g. PictureBoxA and PictureBoxB).  In your button event handlers, call `PictureBoxA.Show()` `and PictureBoxA.Hide()` or vice-versa.  Another way is just use one PictureBox control and call the `load` method each time a button is pressed to replace its picture with the correct one.